# Что такое "присный"?

Tags: старославянский

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что значит слово "присный"? Например, "приснопамятный" - это памятный вечно или как? Или, например, в окончании молитв: "И ныне, и присно, и во веки веков".
Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Присно - устаревшее значение, оставшееся в религиозной литературе,- "всегда, вечно,"

"И ныне, и присно, и во веки веков" -"и нынче, и всегда, и вечно" -градация, вечно как бы усиливает значение.Всегда-это постоянно сейчас, а вечно - в веках.

Answer (score 4):

В церковных выражениях означает  : истинный, настоящий, вечный. Приснодева, присность (вечность), присносущен.
В слегка ироничном значении употребляется прилагательное *присный (присные)*, которым характеризуют верных приближенных кого-либо.

> Никита Хрущев. Воспоминания (1971)
> Дескать, в них виновны Ягода, Ежов, Берия, Абакумов и **их присные.**

Приснопамятный - широко и давно известный (с негативным оттенком).

Comment: По моему мнению, русским не следует использовать слово "присно".

P.S. Не умножайте сущности без крайней необходимости.

Comment: А,  что ?  Часто  используют ?

Answer (score 0):

Присно - пристно. Преустановленное- прежде установленное. С древних времён.

Comment: Подробнее, не через ступеньку, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

присно=Присно - пристно. Преустановленное- прежде установленное. С древних времён. добавлю: а следовательно верное и сейчас. У латинян P3AESENTES (все наверное помнят по школе презент пёфект). У этрусков PRESN-TS.т.е. наш вариант по звучанию ближе К ЭТРУСКАМ  чем  латинянам.